# What are the current most challenging MNIST-like tasks aiming to achieve the lowest error rate?

Tags: data-request, ai

For example there is [the MNIST database](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MNIST_database) which is used to test ANN, however it's not so challenging, because some hierarchical systems of *convolutional neural networks* manages to get an error rate of 0.23 percent and the same with other OCR tests.

Therefore OCR datasets are '*no longer perceived as an exemplar of "artificial intelligence"*'<sup>[wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artificial_intelligence)</sup>.

Are there any similar equivalent image-recognition tests, especially these which have the most challenging tasks with dataset which are commonly used as benchmark tests to challenge the AI which are fairly reliable and they're possible to pass (e.g. by humans), but most AAN are struggling to achieve the lower error rate?

Comment: Re-posted from [AI](http://ai.stackexchange.com/q/1392/8), then from [stats](http://stats.stackexchange.com/q/228592/12989) in hope that's the right place for this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure if this is what you're looking for, but I've recently published the [HASYv2 dataset](https://arxiv.org/abs/1701.08380). It contains 369 classes and 168233 recordings in total. The best classification result I could get was about 82% accuracy.

The data is extremely similar to MNIST. For more information, I recommend reading the paper. But if the paper doesn't answer questions, feel free to ask me :-)